# MATCH-formula where 'lookup_value' is array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I have 3 Excel-files (automated exports) that contain the following information:

**1. The total list of shelves in one particular store:**

```
| Shelf_code |
|------------|
| AB01       |
| AA02       |
```

**2. The total list of all shelves linked to each article**

```
| SKU_code | Shelf_code |
|----------|------------|
| 111      | AA01       |
| 111      | AB01       |
| 111      | AC01       |
| 112      | AA01       |
```

**3. The list of all available SKUs**

```
| SKU_code | Other stuff |
|----------|-------------|
| 111      | ...         |
| 112      | ...         |
| 113      | ...         |
| 114      | ...         |
```

And what I want to do is to link the Shelf_codes from that specific store to the total available SKU-list, so it will look like this:

```
| SKU_code | Other stuff | Shelf_code_store1 |
|----------|-------------|-------------------|
| 111      | ...         | AB01              |
| 112      | ...         |                   |
| 113      | ...         |                   |
| 114      | ...         | AB01              |
```

I have tried to embed the MATCH formula within another INDEX/MATCH formula (see code below) which was partially successful since this will only work if the shelf_code in file 2 happens to be the first one to match the SKU_code.

Since this will be mostly not the case, it will return a #N/A error

```
MATCH(
  INDEX({file2_shelfcode},MATCH(file3_skucode,{file2_skucode},0)),
  {file1_shelfcode}
)
```

Does anyone has a solution for this?
Since these files contain over 1000 articles, 200 shelves, 6 stores, and will be frequently updated I don't think using a Pivottable on file 2 will fit my needs.

Comment: For this an array might be better to use then `INDEX/MATCH`, I would maybe try a `INDEX/SMALL/IF` array. Documentation: https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-multiple-matches-into-separate-rows
This might be your solution to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49671419/6387479)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel Index to look up multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49670563/excel-index-to-look-up-multiple-values)